# Mesh doen’t follow armature in object mode, in pose mode it does

Tags: mesh, armature

Hello Blender Stack Exchange,

I have made a character, and I want to animate it. My character consists on a few meshes, all of which were parented to the armature. My problem is: when I move the character around, some parts of the mesh (wing feathers) do not follow it.

In pose mode, everything works fine
[image]

In object mode wings stay behind

[image]

Wings have armature modifier with "Object" filled with correct armature
I have read similar questions, but none of the solutions for them seemed suitable

1. How can I make wing's feathers follow my armature?
2. I am planning to make my character walk around. Is it a good idea to move the charater in pose mode, therefore leaving origin point far away from the character, or there is a more correct way to animate charcter's covering long distences?

I pretty new to Blender and I would appreciate any help. I am using Blender 3.6.0
Here is the link to my file https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3Qsm/fivRe41tY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select wings, select armature, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, choose "Armature deform".
thank you joseph